# Remove color blending in javascript heatmap?

Tags: javascript, colors, heatmap, contour, blending

I am making a visualization using [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) by Patrick Wied.

**Question: How can I remove the color blending in a heatmap?**

Instead of blending/blurring the colors, I would like the colors to look layered like so: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbfm4.png]

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 weeks now... If anyone could help me, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two weeks?

```
gradient: {
    0     : '#00f',
    0.2   : '#00f',
    0.2001: '#0ff',
    0.4   : '#0ff',
    0.4001: '#0f0',
    0.6   : '#0f0',
    0.6001: '#ff0',
    0.8   : '#ff0',
    0.8001: '#f00',
    1     : '#f00'
}
```

I haven't tested this, but then again I have never used heatmap.js. I just looked at the docs for thirty seconds, and I figure this should work.

Comment: and yes, two weeks sadly.

Comment: -offers reassuring pats on the back- Sometimes it helps to take a step back and work on something else for a while ;)